# Using variable from a class into another class

Tags: python, variables, maya

I am trying to use a variable from a class - `CustomNodeTranslator` and have that variable to be used in another class - `fileImporter`

However I was prompted with the error `# AttributeError: 'CustomNodeTranslator' object has no attribute 'camName' #` I used similar method on another 2 class of mine, and it is working except for this two classes.

Could it be because CustomNodeTranslator is a special case? Seeing that it is used for plugin?

Please do give me advices.

Thank you.

```
class CustomNodeTranslator(OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator):
    def __init__(self):
        OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator.__init__(self)
    ...
    ...

    def reader(self, fileObject, optionString, accessMode):
        try:           
            fullPath = fileObject.fullName()

            self.fileHandle = open(fullPath,"r")
            camHandle = self.fileHandle

            camBaseName = os.path.basename(camHandle.name)
            camName = os.path.splitext(camBaseName)[0]
            self.camName = camName

class fileImporter():
    def __init__(self, order):

        test = CustomNodeTranslator()

        cameraName, cameraShape =  cmds.camera(n=str(test.camName))
        camSel.extend((cameraName, cameraShape))

        cmds.scale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)


        camBaseName = os.path.basename(camHandle.name)
        camName = os.path.splitext(camBaseName)[0]
        self.camName = camName
```

Comment: `test.camName` will only be assigned after `test.reader(...)` is called, as it isn't assigned in `__init__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So I take it, it is impossible to called any other functions unless I assigned it within the `__init__`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Any case that requires the two attributes (`fileHandle` and `camName`) assigned for the first time in `reader` will fail if that method has not yet been called.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think I understand what you are trying to say. I did manage to get it to work but after a while, it fails again due to some of the Maya intervention where it likes to adds in a numerical suffix behind. Even so, my code is getting the domino effects. :( But nevertheless I did got a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create the class attribute in the `__init__` method, so of course *--here--*

```
test = CustomNodeTranslator()
# -- here --
cameraName, cameraShape =  cmds.camera(n=str(test.camName))
```

It's not visible yet. Either assign it in the init or put an attribute reference on the class interface. [More in the doc.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

**UPDATE**: you should declare it in the `CustomNodeTranslator` class

```
class CustomNodeTranslator(OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.camName = ""
        ....
```

Comment: Hi pardon my noobness, but what do you actually means?

Comment: `camName` becomes "available" in the `CustomNodeTranslator` just when it is first declared. So after the instantiation (`CustomNodeTranslator()`) does not have it yet. Only the first time you invoke `reader` you will have it available. My suggestion was then to declare it, even just like `self.camName = ""`, in the `__init__` method.

Comment: so I tried declaring `self.camName = ""` at either of the `__init__` I am still getting this error : `# AttributeError: type object 'CustomNodeTranslator' has no attribute 'camName' # `

Comment: @dissidia as I specified in the update of the answer? Because in that case, according to the language specification at least, it should work

Comment: I tried it out and it is not working as well. I am still getting the same error. I have inserted a few print statements, for some reasons, the `self.camName` is returning in blanks instead of any strings despite it is able to capture the information in the `try` statement

Comment: In order to have the value of `camName` populated with a value you have of course to execute `reader` before. Up to that point it makes sense it is blank: on the __init__ method you just define it. Until you call test.reader(<put the right parameters>) `camName` is blank

Answer (score 0):

Field only exists after you have created it.

```
test = CustomNodeTranslator()
# at this point test only has fields that are either introduced in 
# the __init__
# or in the class body (like methods)
# calling reader with proper arguments will create the field

test.reader(fileObject, optionString, accessMode)
print test.camName
```

Comment: It seems to be giving me more issues such as `# NameError: global name 'fileObject' is not defined #` but thanks anyway

Comment: @dissidia: Yep - you have to have defined them somewhere before.